# iOS (Swift) equivalent for populating a linear layout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I am pretty much new at iOS development, I want to populate Time and Date in a list order in the view(doesnt require any interaction) received in JSON. In android I am doing it by designing a linearlayout template or Item and then inflating it in a loop with modifying Time and Date Textview values in each loop. its pretty straight forward in Android.

In iOS (Xcode 8.3) I am getting the NSArray from the dictionary and successfully able to print it in following order:

```
{
   Date = "Monday07,2017";
   Time = "3:24AM";
}
{
   Date = "Tuesday08,2017";
   Time = "11:03PM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "1:13AM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "4:17PM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "7:17AM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "7:17AM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "7:18AM";
}
{
   Date = "Wednesday08,2017";
   Time = "9:05PM";
}
```

Now I am stuck at weather to use UITable view or UIStackview(And I dont know how to use any of them programmatically) to programmatically inflate each row with Time and Date. more over I just have to show first five key:value pairs and not all the NSArray.

I find UIStackView a better option in this case cuz It wd allow me to add two simple labels without any interactions. I plan to populate each UIStackView in a loop just as I am doing with Linearlayout in Android.

Help I need here is how to put the following NSArray into a list in the view...

Comment: UITableView is a good option to populate this data. You can find a-lot of tutorials online for UITableView. And also for parsing this array the concepts are same as in Android. Just syntax is different.  I'll suggest you understand JSON parsing properly, becuase you'll be using it all the time in development.

http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/12/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-3/

Comment: I probably would have gone with UITableView. Just implement the methods for number of rows (it's the # of elements in your array) and the cell for row. The default UITableViewCell has a few options that easily support displaying the data you have. From memory, that cell should have properties for two labels already (text and detail I believe?).

Comment: Thanks guys, Now I have expert opinion and I'll go for tableview by watching tutorials ofc.

Answer (score 1):

You Should go with UITableview and not UIStackView.
The purpose of a table view is to show big amount of data such as the file you have. Table view will do a lot of things on your behalf one of the most important things which tableView will do it for you it will dequeue your cell and prepares it for reusing which you are not able to do it using StackViews.

On the other hand the purpose of UIStackViews are to help you layout your views easily both vertically and horizontally, and use less UIConstraints.

You can add UIStackViews to any UIView such as your TableViews Cell

There are plenty of tutorials about iOS TableView a good place to start will be [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com)

Comment: Thanks Khalid. I am now going for tableview.

Comment: @Code_Lover best of luck